# Getting selected order type by jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use Adaptive Horizontal Tab Menu plugin to sort my orders based on various conditions (such as newest, most related, etc). I use ajax and partial loading to load filter results. There is no problem to see my selected sort type before sending ajax request. The problem rises when the partial view is replaced inside html. I use Jquery for ajax process. I know i must use some thing like follow, but it does not work at all. I think this is related to the plugin which i am using. i put html and javascript code.

```
 <div id="tabs" class="ah-tab-wrapper dt-sl">
                            <ul id="tabul" class="ah-tab dt-sl orderby">
                                <li id="1" class="ah-tab-item" value="1" data-ah-tab-active="true">
                                    مرتبط ترین
                                </li>
                                <li id="2" class="ah-tab-item" value="2">
                                    پربازدیدترین
                                </li>
                                <li id="3" class="ah-tab-item" value="3">
                                    جدیدترین
                                </li>
                                <li id="4" class="ah-tab-item" value="4">
                                    پرفروش ترین
                                </li>
                                <li id="5" class="ah-tab-item" value="5">
                                    ارزان ترین
                                </li>
                                <li id="6" class="ah-tab-item" value="6">
                                    گران ترین
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tabul.ah-tab li', function (e) {
    alert($(this).val());});
```

By simply selecting this ul by id or it's class does not work. I am really confused. any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: So you want to retrieve all the id rows by order correct? so output needs to be like 1,2,3,4,5,6 in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you need, but using the code below you can display all id's in order.

Or display all `<li>` element which have the `data-ah-tab-active="true"` attribute.

**SNIPPET:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.optionA', function() {
  var arr = $(".ah-tab-item").map(function() {
    return this.id; // RETURN ID OF LI ELEMENT
  });
  $("#result").html(""); // CLEAR DIV RESULTS
  $("#result").append(arr.get().join(", ")); // SHOW RESULTS
});

$(document).on('click', '.optionB', function() {
  var arr = $(".ah-tab-item[data-ah-tab-active=true]").map(function() {
    return this.id; // RETURN ID OF LI ELEMENT
  });
  $("#result").html(""); // CLEAR DIV RESULTS
  $("#result").append(arr.get().join(", ")); // SHOW RESULTS
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs" class="ah-tab-wrapper dt-sl">
  <ul id="tabul" class="ah-tab dt-sl orderby">
    <li id="1" class="ah-tab-item" value="1" data-ah-tab-active="true">ONE</li>
    <li id="2" class="ah-tab-item" value="2">TWO</li>
    <li id="3" class="ah-tab-item" value="3">THREE</li>
    <li id="4" class="ah-tab-item" value="4" data-ah-tab-active="true">FOUR</li>
    <li id="5" class="ah-tab-item" value="5">FIVE</li>
    <li id="6" class="ah-tab-item" value="6">SIX</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" class="optionA btn btn-primary">Display ALL LI id's by current sort</button>
</div>
<button type="button" class="optionB btn btn-secondary">Display ALL LI id's which have attribute "data-ah-tab-active = active"</button>

<div class="card">
  <div id="result" class="card-body">Click a button above</div>
</div>
```